# browser-sync - not able to load js or css files

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

i am trying to serve my app from browser-sync. when my index.html got loaded. i see none of the js/css files getting loaded.

i am using vs code as IDE.

below is my folder structure.

```
 - SampleApp 
    app
      index.html
    bower_components
    node_modules
    gulpfile.js
```

Below is my gulp file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');


gulp.task('index', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('./app/index.html');
  // It's not necessary to read the files (will speed up things), we're only after their paths: 
  var sources = gulp.src(['./app/**/*.js', './app/**/*.css'], {read: false});

  return target.pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}), {name: 'bower'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});


gulp.task('serve', function () {

     browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "app"
        }
    })



    gulp.watch(['*.html', 'app/styles/**/*.css', 'app/**/*.js','app/**/*.html'], { cwd: 'app' }, reload);
});
```

When i run gulp serve.
i can see my site running but not able to load any files.(bower_components / my js files /css files)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
below is my index.html scripts.

```
 <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
       <script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
       <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
       <script src="/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
       <script src="/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
       <script src="/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

please help me with this.

Comment: So what path are files trying to load from in dev tools network?

Comment: this is the network call to one of the file .   Request URL:http://localhost:3002/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:3002

Answer (score 1):

Finally found solution in below link.
https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/125
Always baseDir should be the highest point of our folder structure or define routes to traverse to folders.

Below is the final working gulpfile.js..

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var middleware = require('proxy');


gulp.task('index', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('./index.html');   
  var sources = gulp.src(['./app/**/*.js', './app/**/*.css'], {read: false});

  return target.pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}), {name: 'bower'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});



gulp.task("watch", function () {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir:'./'
        }
    });

     gulp.watch(['app/**/*.html', 'app/styles/**/*.css', 'app/**/*.js','app/**/*.html'], { cwd: './' }, reload);
});
```